# Can return a component directly from useReducer?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

Can I use useReducer to return a component as a complex state?

useReducer always be used to manage data object as a state, once the state changed the component will be re-rendered. The advantage to return component from useReducer is we can put all logic in reducer function, no need to based on state logic change to render specific.

I don't want to write code like this:

```
() => {
  const [state, dispatch] = useReducer((prevState, action) => {
    const {type, payload} = action;
    switch(type) {
      case 'loaded':
        return {...prevState, isLoading: false};
      case 'loading':
        return {...prevState, isLoading: true};
      default:
        return prevState;
    }
  }, {isLoading: true});

  return <>
           {state.isLoading && <Loading />}
           {!state.isLoading && <DoSomething />}
         </>
}
```

Can I do:

```
() => {
  const [state, dispatch] = useReducer((prevState, action) => {
    const {type, payload} = action;
    switch(type) {
      case 'loaded':
        return <DoSomething />;
      case 'loading':
        return <Loading />;
      default:
        return null;
    }
  }, {isLoading: true});

  return <>
           {state}
         </>
}
```

Comment: why not simple `if(state.isLoading) return <Loading />; return <DoSomething />` ?

Comment: `state` is an object and they dont qualify as React.element thus you cant.

Comment: If the question is whether or not you can, the answer is a yes. If the question is whether or not you *should* then I would say the answer is *probably not*. If your components are mostly static then it should fine but as soon as you start trying to do this with increasingly more complex components then you're adding a large overhead of destroying and then creating a new component along with lifecycle events. If anything you're going to give the garbage collector a good workout. I'm curious to know what an actual react expect thinks about this though.

Comment: @apokryfos thank you for reply and I do agree with you, but I'm also curious whether it's anti pattern. Actually return component from useReducer is working fine. There is one example https://codesandbox.io/embed/usereducer-b0lbn

Comment: @Rikin there is one example https://codesandbox.io/embed/usereducer-b0lbn, for me object & React.element should be same thing. I expect Object.is comparison algorithm can also compare React.element.

Comment: @xadm this part just one example, please have a look the real example https://codesandbox.io/embed/usereducer-b0lbn, that is my question.

Comment: write a test for this kind of reducer  ... doable but doesn't make sens in many aspects